# Add views to different layout in Relativelayout which inflate an xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to create a custom View that would replace/inflate a certain layout which contains multiple linearlayout predefined and adding those views into each and every predefined layouts.

My predefined layout contains 4 linearlayouts inside relativelayout as parent and inflating this xml in class where it extends Relativelayout and initialising views as below.

```
private void initView(Context context) {
    //Inflate and attach your child XML
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_empty_views, this);
    llTop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    llLeft = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    llBottom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
    llRight = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout4);
}
```

Now ill accept 12 child views and need to add 3 child to each linearlayout is where im stuck now. In addView function not able to split the the views due to index is always -1.

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (llTop == null) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    } else {
        //Forward these calls to the content view
        llTop.addView(child, index, params);
    }
}
```

In onLayout function, getChildCount is raised more than 12 due to inflating my predefined layout.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    //super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.v("Count::", String.valueOf(getChildCount()));
    /*for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        removeViewAt(i);
        //llTop.addView(v);
        if (i < 3) {
            llTop.addView(v);
        } else if (i > 2 && i < 6) {
            llRight.addView(v);
        } else if (i > 5 && i < 9) {
            llBottom.addView(v);
        } else if (i > 9) {
            llLeft.addView(v);
        }
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an index of -1 is received in [addView(View child, int index)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)), this means it should be added to the end of the ViewGroup.

I'm not sure I exactly understand your intent with this View, you may not need a custom View here. However, I can tell you that you should not be adding views in your [onLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) function. This function is where a View should size and position its children.

Check out the Android Developer's guide on [creating custom views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

Comment: Yes, but how do I move this view to another layout